# Jquery select each checkbox's value when it's in a html table

Tags: jquery

**HTML CODE**

```
<table id="tablechkbx">
    <tr>
        <td>CITY&nbsp;<input value="5" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>DATE OF BIRTH&nbsp;<input value="7" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>DESIGNATION&nbsp;<input value="10" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>EMAIL&nbsp;<input value="1" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>GENDER&nbsp;<input value="12" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>INCOME LEVEL&nbsp;<input value="8" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>INDUSTRY OF EMPLOY&nbsp;<input value="9" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>KIDS&nbsp;<input value="13" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>MARITAL STATUS&nbsp;<input value="11" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>MOBILE NUMBER&nbsp;<input value="2" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>NAME&nbsp;<input value="3" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>NIC NUMBER&nbsp;<input value="6" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>TELEPHONE NUMBER&nbsp;<input value="4" id="datacell" type="checkbox"></td>                
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>                     
       var tds;
       $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#btnselectall').on('click',function(){                  
                    $('#tablechkbx').find('tr').each(function(){
                        tds = $(this).find('td'); 
                        for(var k=0;k<tds.size();k++){
                            var data = tds[i];
                            console.log(data.next("#datacell").val());                           
                        }                        
                    });                    
                });
            });
 </script>
```

I was try to get the checkbox value from above code but it's show an error like `TypeError: data.next is not a function`. But it will print all `td` element when it's use as `console.log(data);`

Comment: Is there more html than this or are you selecting the wrong id? Your table has the id `tablechkbx` but your selector is `'#tbcheckbox'`.

Comment: Also, its invalid html to reuse ids, they should be unique on the page. So you should use `class="datacell"` instead of `id="datacell"` on your inputs

Comment: correct value is `tbcheckbox`. Its copy past error.Because html table is very huge then I made smaller version from actual table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the issues I mentioned in the comments, the reason you are getting `TypeError: data.next is not a function` is because when you use bracket notation and access a jQuery object like an array, it returns the DOM element at that position, not a jQuery object. If you change `var data = tds[i];` to `var data = tds.eq(i);` you will get a jQuery object.

Another way to loop over them would be to use `tds.each(callback)` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)).

An additional issue is that you would need to call `data.children()` instead of `data.next()` (assuming you've fixed `data` to be a jQuery object) since the input you are looking for is a child of the td not a sibling.

Comment: And I used `console.log(data.children().valueOf('input#datacell').val());  `